# Storing 128bit numbers in elastic or mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have design requirement to be able to save an IPv6 address in a decimal format. In java I have BigInteger that can hold 40 digit number and Oracle takes it via JDBC driver just fine.

How can do this in Elastic or Mongo DB. From what I read, max numbers supported in elastic or mongodb are 64bit bigint numbers.
For e.g. if i convert

```
 FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF,
```

decimal format is

```
 340282366920938463463374607431768211455 (total of 39 digits).
```

What is the best way to solve this in elastic or mongo. I need to be able to run range functions (=,<,<=,>=) on this field to search the documents.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Elasticserch 5.0 there is an `ip` [field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html), which supports both IPv4 and IPv6.

I would recommend to go with this one, in Elasticsearch, rather than do integer/string conversion.

The reason for this is that it’s naturally support subnet style queries, which I think is quite handy. E.g.

```
GET index/_search
{
    “query”: {
        “term”: {
            “ip_addr”: “2001:db8::/48”
        }
    }
}
```

Range queries are supported as well for this field type

Comment: Yes, i have tried that. I am using ip type to store actual IP address, but i need to see if I can store decimal as well. Ofcourse if its not possible, i will have to rely on this type.

Comment: @Sannu Just use the [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) feature to index the IP address as an IP as well as a [number](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html).  For 39 digits, you'd probably want to use a `double`.

Comment: @dmbaughman, i use fields to store other stuff such as text and raw of same  text field. But in this case, i need to find a way to store 128 bit decimal. Double and long dont offer enough space. Not sure if there is a way to split this large number into 3 or 4 smaller number and still run queries on these.